# title of content hides behind bootstrap scrollspy

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

what all i need is when you click on respective links such as about us etc it should show the title of the content but as of now the title hides behind the navigation menu..pls help im having very less time for a project. if i add padding to #section it appears proper but on top of the page after the full width image it leaves white space which i dont want.

below is the url

http://squaretechnologies.in/ciomatrix/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put a padding-top on the section ID that is equal to the height of the navigation. You leave it off the home section. You will also have to adjust with a media query when you hit the mobile menu since it's not as tall. Some also suggest a positive padding and negative margin (also equal to the nav height).

That is the actual fix for this outside of using jquery to produce the offset (depending on what specific combination you have). See below for jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("body").scrollspy({target: "#navigation", offset:50});
});
```